# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a node but when I rosrun this node I got Segmentation fault (core dumped). Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

#include <arm_moveit/range_msg.h>
#include <gazebo_msgs/GetModelState.h>
#include <gazebo_msgs/ModelStates.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
const std::string TOPIC = "/gazebo/get_model_state";
const float TABLE_HEIGHT = 0.766;
const float TABLE_LENGTH = 2.0;
const float TABLE_WIDTH = 0.7;

class object_pose
{
private:
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher range_publisher;
  ros::ServiceClient client;
  ros::Subscriber subsriber;
  geometry_msgs::Point tapping_range[2];
  arm_moveit::range_msg msg;

public:
  object_pose();
  ~object_pose();
  void callback(const gazebo_msgs::ModelStates::ConstPtr &robot_model_state);
  void connectServiceAndPublisher();
};
void object_pose::callback(const gazebo_msgs::ModelStates::ConstPtr &robot_model_state)
{
  ROS_INFO("callback function reached");
  geometry_msgs::Pose table_position;
  int table_index = -1;
  std::vector<std::string> model_names = robot_model_state->name;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < model_names.size(); i++)
  {
    if (model_names[i] == "table")
      table_index = i;
  }
  table_position = robot_model_state->pose[table_index];
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Table Position:" << std::endl << table_position);
  // defines tapping starting point
  tapping_range[0].x = table_position.position.x + TABLE_WIDTH / 0.5f;
  tapping_range[0].y = table_position.position.y - TABLE_LENGTH / 0.5f;
  tapping_range[0].z = table_position.position.z + TABLE_HEIGHT;

  // defines tapping ending point
  tapping_range[1].x = table_position.position.x - TABLE_WIDTH / 0.5f;
  tapping_range[1].y = table_position.position.y + TABLE_LENGTH / 0.5f;
  tapping_range[1].z = table_position.position.z + TABLE_HEIGHT;

  ROS_INFO_STREAM("tapping_range:" << std::endl << tapping_range[0]);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("tapping_range:" << std::endl << tapping_range[1]);
  msg.another_field = 2;
  msg.points.push_back(tapping_range[0]);
  msg.points.push_back(tapping_range[1]);
  range_publisher.publish(msg);

}
object_pose::object_pose()
{
}
void object_pose::connectServiceAndPublisher()
{
  range_publisher = n.advertise<arm_moveit::range_msg>("/tapping_range_topic", 1);
  object_pose obj;
  subsriber = n.subscribe("/gazebo/model_states", 1, &object_pose::callback, &obj);
}

object_pose::~object_pose()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "object_pose");
  if (argc != 1)
  {
    ROS_INFO("usage: object_pose 'name'");
    return 1;
  }
  object_pose obj_pose;
  obj_pose.connectServiceAndPublisher();
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

range_msg.msg is defined as:

```
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
uint8 another_field
```

When I rosrun this node, I got:

```
[ INFO] [1602045185.242760021, 27.755000000]: callback function reached
[ INFO] [1602045185.243352804, 27.755000000]: Table Position:
position: 
  x: 1.1
  y: 0
  z: 0
orientation: 
  x: 0
  y: 0
  z: 0
  w: 1

[ INFO] [1602045185.243392476, 27.755000000]: tapping_range:
x: 2.5
y: -4
z: 0.766

[ INFO] [1602045185.243423741, 27.755000000]: tapping_range:
x: -0.3
y: 4
z: 0.766

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362965/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)/) by [sueee](https://answers.ros.org/users/53418/sueee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where does the output come from? In the code you post, there is not this specific output.

One thing I noticed is the following.

```
  object_pose obj;
  subsriber = n.subscribe("/gazebo/model_states", 1, &object_pose::callback, &obj);
```

You shouldn't do this, as you instantiate a new object `obj` and bind the subscriber to the `callback` function of this object. However, `obj` goes out of scope and is destroyed as soon as you leave the `connectServiceAndPublisher` function. Thus, the address of the object `obj` is invalid and whatever the bound `callback` is pointing to is not existing anymore.

It should be:

```
  subsriber = n.subscribe("/gazebo/model_states", 1, &object_pose::callback, this);
```

This way, you bind to the `callback` function of the class instance.

See the [`roscpp_tutorial` and especially the last sentence of the Subscriptions section](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks#Subscriptions)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sueee](https://answers.ros.org/users/53418/sueee/) on 2020-10-12**:
Thanks a lot! This solves my problem

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-10-13**:
@sueee great. Please mark this answer as correct by clicking on the check mark next to it. Thanks.

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2022-09-22**:
Just to comment further on this answer: Segmentation fault occurs when your program tries to access a variable or piece of memory that it does not have access to. As @mgruhler mentioned, obj runs out of scope at the end of the function `connectServiceAndPublisher()`.